# Nooblyf, javascript, simple loop controlled by 3 variables, not sure why it stops looping after 1 iteration

Tags: javascript

**Solved!**,

set var looplim = 9

and the overwrite looplim, to looplim = looplim + 8, instead of setting it to infinite, which was continually decreasing in value, which was reducing the value of looplim, but no longer!

learning to code from codecademy in javascript atm, have some experience with python that I need to completely relearn

Ok, so I wanted to create an example of a potential infinite loop, being limited by, multiple variables. This program basically has 3 retained variables that are both increasing in value, 2 of which are added together, the other is squared. Once the squared value gets larger than the added values, the loop stops! For some reason, the loop only runs once, when it should run 7 times, would really appreciate any advice!

http://hastebin.com/noxumojemo.vhdl

```
var looplim = 1;
var infinite = 8;
var k = 1;

//not sure if I actually need to pass variables to function like this, although, fairly certain i am.
var generator = function(infinite,looplim,k){

    //value of infinite will be slowly increasing, until squared value of k is greater, and subtracted.

    while(infinite >= 8){

        console.log("mobiasMobiasMobias");

        //value of k, is retained, and incremented by 1.

        k = k + 1;

        //looplim increases, by + 8 basically, and is retained.


        looplim = looplim + infinite;


        //loopdestroyer....should be a local variable here, and does not really need to be retained since value k is being passed to it, which is retained.
        loopdestroyer = k*k;


        //new value of infinite is set and retained, the increasing value of looplim, stays above loopdestroyer, for 7 cycles, im pretty sure, unless i'm mathing wrong, looplim being 57, and loopdestroyer being 64, when the loop ends.
        infinite = looplim - loopdestroyer;    
    }
};

generator(infinite,looplim,k);
```

Comment: This question is answerable by debugging the code with [debugging tools](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) available in your browser. [Rubber Duck Debug](http://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. If you are not sure what your code does, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger). Only _then_, ask a question on StackOverflow and _show your research_.

Comment: `9-4 = 5` and `5 < 8` just try debug your code

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to learn a bit more about the rulesets of stack overflow too.

Comment: It is not necessary to edit your post and add "Solved", as it would invalidate the purpose of Stack Overflow as a question and answer site (it would no longer be a question). If your own solution works, you can always post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm reading your code wrong, infinite is getting set as 5 in the first loop

```
var looplim = 1;
var infinite = 8;
var k = 1;

var generator = function(infinite,looplim,k){



   while(infinite >= 8){

      k = k + 1; // k = 2


     looplim = looplim + infinite; // 1 + 8 = 9

     loopdestroyer = k*k;  // k = 2 = 2 * 2 = 4

     infinite = looplim - loopdestroyer;    // 9 - 4  = 5
    }
};

generator(infinite,looplim,k);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the first loop `k` is 2 which makes `loopdestroyer` hold the value 4, `looplim` is 9 here (4*4 + 1) so `looplim - loopdestroyer` gives the value 5 with which `infinity` is set. That makes `infinity` smaller than 8 so the loop ends.

Please use `console.log` extensively, it helps.

Comment: where you find `4*4+1`?

Comment: @Grundy I don't have the faintest idea. C&P error? Probably. Sorry for that.